# Undefined Path In Django

Tags: django

I am working on a django application and everything is working fine except I am getting an error **Not Found: /about-us/undefined** when I visit the url 127.0.0.1:8000/about-us/

With a view as below the error is not showing:

```
def about_us(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return HttpResponse('<h1>About Page</h1>')
```

But when I render an HTML template as shown below then the error shows

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'website_files/index.html', {'home' : True})
```

**website.urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('about-us/', views.about_us, name="about-us"),
    path('why_us/', views.why_us, name="why_us"),
    path('out_team/', views.out_team, name="out_team"),
    path('it_solutions/', views.it_solutions, name="it_solutions"),
    path('it_solutions/it_management_services', views.it_management_services, name="it_management_services"),
    path('it_solutions/cyber_security_services', views.cyber_security_services, name="cyber_security_services"),
    path('it_solutions/software_dev_services', views.software_dev_services, name="software_dev_services"),
    path('it_solutions/networking_and_cloud_services', views.networking_services, name="networking_and_cloud_services"),
    path('it_solutions/it_consultations', views.consulting_services, name="it_consultations"),
    path('it_solutions/data_backup_and_recovery', views.backup_services, name="data_backup_and_recovery"),
    path('it_solutions/email_hosting', views.email_hosting, name="email_hosting"),
    path('it_solutions/web_hosting', views.web_hosting, name="web_hosting"),
    path('stories', views.blogging, name="stories"),
    path('contact_us', views.contact, name="contact_us"),
    path('find_out', views.find_out, name="find_out"),
    path('request_quote', views.get_quote, name="request_quote"),
]
```

main urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('website.urls')),   
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

What am I missing? You assistance will greatly appriciated.

**Edit**
Below is the index.html
**index.html**

```
{% extends 'website_files/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

  <section class="slider">
    <div class="slick-carousel carousel-arrows-light carousel-dots-light m-slides-0"
      data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 1, "arrows": true, "dots": true, "speed": 700,"fade": true,"cssEase": "linear"}'>
      <div class="slide-item align-v-h bg-overlay">
        <div class="bg-img"><img src="{% static 'assets/images/sliders/Top-6-Software-Development-Methodologies.jpg' %}" alt="slide img"></div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-7">
              <div class="slide-item__content">
                <h2 class="slide-item__title">Latest Software To Your Possible Customers!!</h2>
                <p class="slide-item__desc">We are experienced professionals who understand that IT services are
                  changing, and are true partners who care about your success.</p>
                <a href="{% url 'contact_us' %}" class="btn btn__primary btn__hi">Get Started</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide-item align-v-h bg-overlay">
        <div class="bg-img"><img src="{% static 'assets/images/sliders/Online-Presence.jpg' %}" alt="slide img"></div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-7">
              <div class="slide-item__content">
                <h2 class="slide-item__title">Online Presence <br> To Ensure High Availability.</h2>
                <p class="slide-item__desc">We understand the importance of having an online presence. We are therefore, strive to help you have a digital footprint</p>
                <a href="{% url 'contact_us' %}" class="btn btn__primary btn__primary-style2 btn__hi">Get Started</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="features-layout3 pt-0 pb-90 bg-gray">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
          <div class="row features-wrapper">
            
            <div class="col-sm-4 feature-item">
              <h4 class="feature-item__title">Software Asset</h4>
              <p class="feature-item__desc">All aspects of your software assets including development, purchasing, deployment &
                maintenance.</p>
              <a href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-right icon-outlined"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 feature-item">
              <h4 class="feature-item__title">Enterprise Services</h4>
              <p class="feature-item__desc">Ranging from but not limited to IT Counsultation, Software Development, Email Hosting etc.</p>
              <a href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-right icon-outlined"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 feature-item">
              <h4 class="feature-item__title">Custom Requests</h4>
              <p class="feature-item__desc">We build bespoke and dynamic systems with associated workflows, and tasks.</p>
              <a href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-right icon-outlined"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature-item feature-item-custom bg-primary">
            
            <h4 class="feature-item__title">Thinking insights, verified and realtime information help you
              make the right decisions!
            </h4>
            <a href="{% url 'it_solutions' %}" class="btn btn__white btn__link">
              <span>Find Your Solution</span><i class="icon-arrow-right icon-outlined"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="about-layout6 bg-gray pt-0 pb-0">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row heading-layout2 mb-70">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h2 class="heading__subtitle color-body">Nationwide Service, Local Expertise</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-7">
          <h3 class="heading__title mb-30">Keep your business safe & ensure high availability.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-5 about__Text">
          <h5 class=" mb-30">Message from our Founder.</h5>
          <p>Here at <b>TechTitan</b>, we strive to help you improve efficiency, leverage tech, and provide better customer experiences with the modern technology
            services available all over the world. Our skilled personnel, utilising the latest technologies
            combined with decades of experience will help you and your business archieve the standard that you strive for and give you a competitive advantage over your peers</p>
          <!-- <img src="{% static 'assets/images/about/Isaac.jpg' %}" alt="singnture" class="mb-20"> -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper bg-white">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-end">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-7">
            <div class="about__img">
              <img src="{% static 'assets/images/about/IMG_0752.jpg' %}" alt="about">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5">
            <ul class="list-items list-unstyled mb-30" style="margin-top: -500px;">
              <li> Continued support to our clients</li>
              <li> Provided the best solutions that your need</li>
              <li> Ensuring that you are moving with the changing worldmwith our updates</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="{% url 'about-us' %}" class="btn btn__primary btn__icon btn__xl">
              <span>More About Us</span><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
            </a>
          </div> -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="services-layout2 services-masonry bg-no-repeat bg-size-auto bg-top-right pt-130 pb-90">
    <div class="bg-img"><img src="{% static 'assets/images/backgrounds/6.png' %}" alt="background"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
          <div class="heading heading-layout2 text-center mb-50">
            <h2 class="heading__subtitle">Only settle for the best</h2>
            <h3 class="heading__title">Our technology allows you to offer the best service to your possible
              customers!
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row services-wrapper">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="service-item">
            <div class="service-item__content">
              <div class="service-item__icon">
                <i class="icon-server"></i>
              </div>
              <h4 class="service-item__title">IT Management <br> Services</h4>
              <p class="service-item__desc">IT management services that manages and oversees the IT infrastructure of your
                organization responsible for networking and operations.</p>
              <a href="{% url 'it_management_services' %}" class="btn btn__secondary btn__link">
                <span>Read More</span>
                <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="service-item__overlay bg-overlay bg-overlay-primary">
              <div class="bg-img"><img src="{% static 'assets/images/services/1.jpg' %}" alt="background"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="service-item">
            <div class="service-item__content">
              <div class="service-item__icon">
                <i class="icon-cloud"></i>
              </div>
              <h4 class="service-item__title">Cyber Security<br> Services</h4>
              <p class="service-item__desc">Drive your business and manage risk with us when it comes
                cyber security, cloud, and manage security services and extend your team with leading experts.</p>
              <a href="{% url 'cyber_security_services' %}" class="btn btn__secondary btn__link">
                <span>Read More</span>
                <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="service-item__overlay bg-overlay bg-overlay-primary">
              <div class="bg-img"><img src="{% static 'assets/images/services/2.jpg' %}" alt="background"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="service-item">
            <div class="service-item__content">
              <div class="service-item__icon">
                <i class="icon-programming"></i>
              </div>
              <h4 class="service-item__title">Software Development<br> Services</h4>
              <p class="service-item__desc">We develop solutions that help you make informed decisions that keep your business going forward especially with rapid changes we face on a daily basis.</p>
              <a href="{% url 'software_dev_services' %}" class="btn btn__secondary btn__link">
                <span>Read More</span>
                <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="service-item__overlay bg-overlay bg-overlay-primary">
              <div class="bg-img"><img src="{% static 'assets/images/services/5.jpg' %}" alt="background"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="service-item">
            <div class="service-item__content">
              <div class="service-item__icon">
                <i class="icon-network"></i>
              </div>
              <h4 class="service-item__title">Networking and Cloud Computing<br> Services</h4>
              <p class="service-item__desc">Cloud computing is the on-demand, availability of computer system
                resources, especially data storage and computing power, without direct active management by the user.
              </p>
              <a href="{% url 'networking_and_cloud_services' %}" class="btn btn__secondary btn__link">
                <span>Read More</span>
                <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="service-item__overlay bg-overlay bg-overlay-primary">
              <div class="bg-img"><img src="{% static 'assets/images/services/3.jpg' %}" alt="background"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="service-item">
            <div class="service-item__content">
              <div class="service-item__icon">
                <i class="icon-technician"></i>
              </div>
              <h4 class="service-item__title">IT Consulting <br> Services</h4>
              <p class="service-item__desc">Trying to implement new technologies can be a challenge. With us on you side, we will give you information on the current technologies to ensure you have the best technologies possible.</p>
              <a href="{% url 'it_consultations' %}" class="btn btn__secondary btn__link">
                <span>Read More</span>
                <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="service-item__overlay bg-overlay bg-overlay-primary">
              <div class="bg-img"><img src="{% static 'assets/images/services/4.jpg' %}" alt="background"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="service-item">
            <div class="service-item__content">
              <div class="service-item__icon">
                <i class="icon-file"></i>
              </div>
              <h4 class="service-item__title">Backup & Recovery<br> Services</h4>
              <p class="service-item__desc">While you can’t predict unexpected events, we’ll ensure the right
                precautions are in place to minimize downtime and keep you moving in the right direction.</p>
              <a href="{% url 'data_backup_and_recovery' %}" class="btn btn__secondary btn__link">
                <span>Read More</span>
                <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="service-item__overlay bg-overlay bg-overlay-primary">
              <div class="bg-img"><img src="{% static 'assets/images/services/6.jpg' %}" alt="background"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5">
          <p class="fz-16 my-4">Trusted by multiple organizations, for 5 years and running, it has been
            delivering
            smiles to hundreds of IT advisors, developers, users, and business owners.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-7 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
          <a href="{% url 'it_solutions' %}" class="btn btn__secondary btn__hi mr-30">Find Your Solution</a>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="features" class="features-layout1 pt-130 pb-220">
    <div class="bg-img"><img src="{% static 'assets/images/backgrounds/10.jpg' %}" alt="background"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-6">
          <div class="heading heading-layout2 mb-40">
            <h2 class="heading__subtitle color-body">Ensure High Availability of Your Services</h2>
            <h3 class="heading__title color-white">Easy solutions for all difficult IT problems, keep businesses safe &
              ensure high availability.</h3>
          </div>
          <a href="{% url 'contact_us' %}" class="btn btn__white btn__bordered btn__xl btn__icon minwidth-170">
            <span>Get Started</span>
            <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-6">
          <div class="row features-wrapper mt-40">
            <div class="col-sm-6 feature-item">
              <div class="feature-item__icon">
                <i class="icon-statistic"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <h4 class="feature-item__title mb-0">Software Development</h4>
                <a href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-right icon-outlined"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 feature-item">
              <div class="feature-item__icon">
                <i class="icon-management"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <h4 class="feature-item__title mb-0">IT Counsultation</h4>
                <a href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-right icon-outlined"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 feature-item">
              <div class="feature-item__icon">
                <i class="icon-software"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <h4 class="feature-item__title mb-0">Email Hosting</h4>
                <a href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-right icon-outlined"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 feature-item">
              <div class="feature-item__icon">
                <i class="icon-relational"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <h4 class="feature-item__title mb-0">Website Hosting</h4>
                <a href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-right icon-outlined"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mt-50 contact-text">
            <div class="col-sm-9 px-0">
              <strong class="color-white">If you have any questions or need help, feel free to contact with our team,
                or call
                <a href="#">(+260) 966477311</a></strong>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 px-0 d-flex justify-content-end">
              <a href="{% url 'contact_us' %}" class="btn btn__primary btn__primary-style2 minwidth-120">Contact Us</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div class="bg-no-repeat bg-top">
    <div class="bg-img"><img src="{% static 'assets/images/backgrounds/11.jpg' %}" alt="backgrounds"></div>

    <section id="contact" class="contact-layout2 pt-0">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="contact-panel d-flex flex-wrap mt--170">
              <div class="contact-panel__banner bg-overlay bg-overlay-primary d-flex flex-column justify-content-between" style="background-color:red">
                <div class="bg-img"><img src="{% static 'assets/images/banners/6.jpg' %}" alt="background"></div>
                <div class="heading heading-layout2 heading-light">
                  <h3 class="heading__title mb-30">Perfect Solutions For Your Business!</h3>
                  <p class="heading__desc mb-30">TechTitan has been helping organizations throughout the World to manage
                    their IT with our unique approach to technology management and consultancy solutions. </p>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
                  <a href="{% url 'contact_us' %}" class="btn btn__white btn__bordered btn__icon">
                    <span>Get Started</span><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>

              <form class="contact-panel__form" method="post" action="{% url 'find_out' %}" id="contactForm">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="contact-name">Name (required)</label>
                      <input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="contact-name" name="contact-name"
                        required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="contact-email">Email (required)</label>
                      <input type="email" required class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="contact-email"
                        name="contact-email" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="contact-Phone">Inquiry (required)</label>
                      <select required class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select Service</option>
                        <option value="Email Hosting">IT Management</option>
                        <option value="IT Counsultation">Cyber Security</option>
                        <option value="Software Development">Software Development</option>
                        <option value="Website Developemnt">Networking And Cloud Computing</option>
                        <option value="Website Developemnt">IT Consulting</option>
                        <option value="Website Developemnt">Backup & Recovery</option>
                        <option value="Website Developemnt">Email Hosting</option>
                        <option value="Website Developemnt">Website Hosting</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="contact-message">Additional Details (required)</label>
                      <textarea required class="form-control" placeholder="Describe your inquiry!" id="contact-message"
                        name="contact-message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn__secondary btn__xl btn__block">Submit Request </button>
                    <div class="contact-result"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <section class="clients border-top pt-50 pb-50">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <div class="slick-carousel"
            data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 6, "arrows": false, "dots": false, "autoplay": true,"autoplaySpeed": 2000, "infinite": true, "responsive": [ {"breakpoint": 992, "settings": {"slidesToShow": 4}}, {"breakpoint": 767, "settings": {"slidesToShow": 3}}, {"breakpoint": 480, "settings": {"slidesToShow": 2}}]}'>
            <div class="client">
              <img src="{% static 'assets/images/clients/1.jpg' %}" alt="client">
              <img src="{% static 'assets/images/clients/1.jpg' %}" alt="client">
            </div>
            <div class="client">
              <img src="{% static 'assets/images/clients/Techmasters.png' %}" alt="client">
              <img src="{% static 'assets/images/clients/Techmasters.png' %}" alt="client">
            </div>
            <div class="client">
              <img src="{% static 'assets/images/clients/idsp.jpg' %}" alt="client">
              <img src="{% static 'assets/images/clients/idsp.jpg' %}" alt="client">
            </div>
            <div class="client">
              <img src="{% static 'assets/images/clients/4.png' %}" alt="client">
              <img src="{% static 'assets/images/clients/4.png' %}" alt="client">
            </div>
            <div class="client">
              <img src="{% static 'assets/images/clients/5.png' %}" alt="client">
              <img src="{% static 'assets/images/clients/5.png' %}" alt="client">
            </div>
            <div class="client">
              <img src="{% static 'assets/images/clients/6.png' %}" alt="client">
              <img src="{% static 'assets/images/clients/6.png' %}" alt="client">
            </div>
            <div class="client">
              <img src="{% static 'assets/images/clients/7.png' %}" alt="client">
              <img src="{% static 'assets/images/clients/7.png' %}" alt="client">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="banner-layout2 pt-0 pb-100">
    <div class="bg-img"><img src="{% static 'assets/images/backgrounds/brickred.svg' %}" alt="background"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-5">
          <div class="banner-text">
            <div class="heading-layout2 heading-light mb-40">
              <h3 class="heading__title mb-30">Timely service delivery!!</h3>
              <p class="heading__desc">We ensure that the services we offer are delivered when they are scheduled for. No delays because we understand that your business as to go forward at all times.
              </p>
            </div>
            <a href="{% url 'contact_us' %}" class="btn btn__white btn__bordered btn__hi mb-30">Get Started</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-7">
          <div class="banner-img">
            <img src="{% static 'assets/images/logo/TechTitan_Logo_1.jpg' %}" alt="banner">
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Post your `index.html` please. You seem to have a redirect in that template.

Comment: Hi Selcuk, this has been done.

Comment: Did you manage to figure out the issue? I am struggling with the same at home page.

Comment: For me it turned out to be the issue in the revolution slider. If I render bullets then for some reason it makes a request at /undefined path. I have removed the bullets settings in the JS of slider and it works fine now.